# Parse iOS, cloud code and background job

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to understand how to use cloud code and background job efficiently for my iOS app.

**First question** about Parse cloud code :    - **SOLVED** -

I need to fetch all my User and check if the nickname is already taken when a new user sign up. (column nickname is a custom column in User table).
So this can be a big request and a cloud code function would be necessary I think ??

**Second question** about Parse background job :

I need to fetch all objects from a Table and check for every object 1 column : dateEnd.
If  dateEnd < date of Today then I put the column Enable to False. How can I do that ? and can the function run 24/24 7/7 ?

[image]

I'm coding only in swift, I guess I will have to take a look at javascript.
Thanks

Comment: The nickname query is quite simple - just whereKey nickname=Desired name. You don't need cloud code for that. You can use a cloud code background job to disable users. You can't run it 24/7 but you can schedule it to run pretty frequently; I wouldn't imagine it would take long to run. Yes, it will need to be in JavaScript

Comment: Ok but if I have 100.000 users I will need cloud code to fetch all this big data ?

Comment: The nickname search will happen on the Parse cloud and it will return 0 or 1 objects. It doesn't retrieve all data and filter it in the local device; that would be insane.

Comment: ok thx so cloud code is useful only when u need to retrieve many values in local ?

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

If your nickname must be unique, why not use the nickname as your username? This way, Parse does this check for you with no effort by you.

If for some reason this is not possible, then simply do a query from your client with a nickname constraint:

```
query.whereKey("nickname", equalTo: chosenNickname)
```

If this does not return any results, then nickname is not taken.

**Second question**

Why do you need to have this job going all the time? Is it important that the Enable column is set to false within seconds or minutes of the expiry? Could expiry be set to happen on the hour? Or at a specific time each day? If this was i.e. like handling at 30 day trial, the trial doesn't need to end at an arbitrary timestamp for every user. It could end at midnight 30 days after trial start. Consider whether your expiry can be more lenient.

Comment: I'm using the email as username to log user only with email. That's why I create a custom column Nickname. Secondly, the enable champ should disable as soon as possible, because the user should not see the object if enable = false. So a check every second would be perfect. A minute at the most.

Comment: Please explain how this enable-thing is working. What causes the object to be disabled?

Comment: check if "dateEnd" is inferior at the date of now. If it's right, then "enable" = false

Comment: why does "dateEnd" have to be for a specific second? why not i.e. on the hour? or at midnight or something, like i suggested earlier?

Comment: because in my app you should not see the object if is disable. It can be disable in a minute, it will be ok, but not an hour

Comment: so why don't you fix this status when someone disables it? how are objects disabled? you should explain the use case if you want us to think about your problem. if not, we can only think within the narrow constraints of what you have already thought

Comment: I just told how the object are disabled. What I need is help on how to create the function in Parse background job. thx

Answer (score 0):

I used to do only get/refresh/save object on iOS side, everything else (I think) should be done on cloud code. Never had troubles with background jobs with such approach.

Comment: So my background job can run in a loop 24/24 7/7 ?